# Changing the background of a button based on slider value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a button that changes color based on the value of a slider.  It should be yellow when the page loads, red if value = 1, blue if value = 2, green if value =3.

Right now no matter what the value, the button turns red.  What am I missing?

html:

```
<input type="button" id="demo" style="background: yellow">
<input id="demorange" type="range" min="1" max="3" onchange="myFunction()">
```

js:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var y = document.getElementById("demorange");
  if (y= 1) { 
    x.style.background = "red";
  } else if (y= 2) { 
    x.style.background = "blue";
  } else if (y= 3) {
    x.style.background = "green";
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (y= 1)` should be `if (y.value == 1)`, similarly for the other conditions. A simpler way would be `x.style.background = {1: "red", 2: "blue", 3: "green"}[y.value];`.

Comment: Your if statements. if(y = 1) is always true. if(y == 1) checks if y actually equals 1. Gotta use double = (==).

Comment: Confused at the downvotes here, the question may be simple but it's still a valid question

Comment: @N.J.Dawson Lack of research effort. There’s a close reason specifically for questions caused by typos.

Comment: @Xufox A novice researches like a novice, if someone doesn't understand the fundamentals of why their code isn't working they won't know how to research how to make it work. I don't think a lack of knowledge is applicable reasoning as to mark an answer as low quality, that's the point of the site isn't it?

Comment: @N.J.Dawson Hundreds of questions daily asking what’s wrong with `if(x = 1)` is neither preferable nor the point of this site. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212).

Comment: I think close votes are reasonable, but the downvotes slightly less so. Why  be redundant? Close votes are intended to be much nucer to a newbie than a big fat `-2` vote count.

Comment: That being said, it doesn't deserve UPvotes, either.

Comment: I would use `y.valueAsNumber` and `===` for comparisons.

Comment: The question isn't "what’s wrong with if(x = 1)", they do not know that's their problem, which makes that not a problem here

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera `y.value` is easier to understand and more applicable to other types of inputs. Plus, `==` vs. `===` is a matter of opinion, and is heavily debated. (Although your method is perfectly fine too).

Comment: @N.J.Dawson That’s what the question boils down to. “What’s wrong with this code: … `if(x = 1){`…`}` …?”. Still neither desirable nor the point of this site. Such errors are trivially detectable by either [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) or using tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or carefully reading the tutorial or documentation. As such it’s not useful for future readers.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson I agree that research is a hard thing to use against newbie questions. If they knew their problem, at a level this basic, they'd know how to fix it as well, and wouldn't need to research it. They can't research it because they don't know it. With basic problems they really can't research it, they just have to learn it, like how they're doing here.

Comment: @Xufox It is useful though, just based on how many questions get asked. Although to be fair they wouldn't know how to find the solution with a problem like this, and they'd be unlikely to end up here.

Comment: @Feathercrown This is exactly why it’s _not_ useful.

Comment: @Xufox Yeah....

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` to compare the values rather than `==`; this will always be true (causing it to always use the first `if` branch) and will also set your variable to the value you're testing for!

You also need to use `y.value` instead of just `y` so you get the value of the input, not the element itself.

Fixed code:

Html:

```
<input type="button" id="demo" style="background: yellow">
<input id="demorange" type="range" min="1" max="3" onchange="myFunction()">
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var y = document.getElementById("demorange");
  if (y.value == 1) { 
    x.style.background = "red";
  } else if (y.value == 2) { 
    x.style.background = "blue";
  } else if (y.value == 3) {
    x.style.background = "green";
  }
}
```

Comment: @Xufox Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

https://plnkr.co/edit/En8G8MkjDLBFMNbGNwC1?p=preview

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var y = document.getElementById("demorange").value;
  if (y== 1) { 
    x.style.background = "red";
  } else if (y== 2) { 
    x.style.background = "blue";
  } else if (y== 3) {
    x.style.background = "green";
  }
}
```

Couple of things:

- Boolean condition equals is `==`. you had `=`
- y is the element, while it should be the value of the element. so need to replace `y=document.getElementById("demorange")` to `y=document.getElementById("demorange").value`

**So why did it turn to red at all?**

In javascript, the expression `y=1` will return the value `1`.

And in a boolean expression, `1` is the same as true `true`

So the expression `if (y=1){ .. }` would be evaluated to true,

Answer (score 0):

In your iff statements you are assigning the value not comparing
change to:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("demo");
 var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("demorange").value);
 if (y === 1) { 
   x.style.background = "red";
 } else if (y === 2) { 
   x.style.background = "blue";
 } else if (y === 3) {
   x.style.background = "green";
 }
```

etc...

Comment: thanx for pointing that out, guess I glossed over that part of the code going to the obvious error

Answer (score 0):

you should use **y.value** to get the data inside the input button, and also you should use **"=="** in boolean statements, instead of "=", which is used in declarations.

like this:

```
  if (y.value == 1) { 
    x.style.background = "red";
  } else if (y.value == 2) { 
    x.style.background = "blue";
  } else if (y.value == 3) {
    x.style.background = "green";
  }
}
```